Getting user input using fgets()
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char color[50];
    char pluralNoun[50];
    char future[50];

    printf("Enter a color: ");
    scanf("%s", color);
    printf("Enter a plural noun: ");
    scanf("%s", pluralNoun);
    printf("Enter a girl you love: ");
    fgets(future, 50, stdin);

    printf("Your favorite color are %s\n", color);
    printf("%s are blue\n", pluralNoun);
    printf("I love %s\n", future);


    return 0;
}

why the result like this:
Enter a color: tes
Enter a plural noun: tes
Enter a girl you love: Your favorite color are tes
tes are blue
I love 

i've tried to move char and fgets to bottom, but nothing change

Please see scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer. It's better not to mix your input methods until you are 100% familiar with their quirks.

Two other problems: not protecting against buffer overflow from scanf(), and fgets() keeps the newline in the buffer, which should be removed. The way those two functions handle a newline is totally different.
